# How to get the root folder in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extesion for the first time and I am following the only guide that explains something about that: [HTML5 ROCKS - FILESYSTEM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).
I need to get storage for my extension and I resolved so:

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(window.PERSISTENT,1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

Ok, it works. 
Now I need to create a xml file into the root, but in "onInitFs" the "fs" var is only a number and "fs.root" can't get it.

```
function onInitFs(fs){

    console.log(fs.root); // -> Undefined

    fs.root.getFile('list.xml', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.isFile === true;
        fileEntry.name == 'list.xml';
        fileEntry.fullPath == '/list.xml';

    }, errorHandler); 
}
```

Can anybody explain why it doesn't work and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using RequestFileSystem within Chrome Extension

In order to use the FileSystem API as a root filesystem for your Chrome extension, you can actually use `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` instead of `requestQuota`.

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {      
        console.log(filesystem);                
        console.log(filesystem.root);
}, function (e) { console.log("Could not request File System"); });
```

This does print correctly on Chrome 15,16 and 17 for me:

```
DOMFileSystem
DirectoryEntry
```

---

### Using requestQuota for HTML5 apps

Just for reference, this would be the way to actually request the quota (i.e., when not using a Chrome Extension). You have to request the quota (the user sees a little banner at the top of his/her window) first. The RequestFileSystem is called if the user accepts.

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 
}, function(e) {
  console.log('Error requesting filesystem', e); 
});
```

Eventually it might be necessary to request quota within an extension. Currently this can be circumvented with the `unlimitedStorage` permission. For the current state of implementation/storage types, see http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage.html

Comment: I've just updated the comment to show how to request storage from the user before allocating the file system. It might be necessary to set the `unlimitedStorage` permission to allocate storage *without* requesting it first.

Answer (score 0):

Until current stable version 17.x, you cannot use HTML5 FileSystem API in Chrome extension. I have try this, the browser will crash down if I call FileSystem API in background page.

And here is a HTML5 API list what you can use in Chrome extension: 
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_other.html

Comment: This is not correct. I've successfully used the HTML5 FileSystem API since Chrome 15, and I believe it has been implemented in Chrome 12.

Comment: I didn't find that whitepapers for storage in chrome developer site. Thanks for telling me that and it indeed works though there is a little different from using in normal web page.